# Induced electric field and electric field due to charges obey superposition?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, superposition

Say a group of charges and a varying magnetic field exists in some region.

We'll have two electric fields,due to the charges and due to the magnetic induction.

Does the total electric field equal the sum of individual fields if the other wasn't present?
Can we prove it or is it an empirical fact?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These fields do obey the superposition. The reason for this is that Maxwell equations are linear equations, and a sum of solutions of these equations is also a solution. In particular, plane waves, as well as the fields created by point charges, charge distributions, magnetic moments or electric currents are all solutions of Maxwell equations.

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking about it.